# Setup Tor Browser as a regular browser

Tags: browsers

How do you setup Tor Browser as a regular browser?

I want everything working just like with a regular browser, all tracking cookies etc. working just with relay.

At the moment I am trying to foolproof a website that has an affiliate program.

Is it possible to setup Tor as a regular browser where the tracking information gets send back to the server as 'HEY affiliate 45878 has received a lead from UK'.

Is this possible currently with Tor only?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it. Tor Browser has been design exactly to stop such tracking attempts. It would appear to me that you want to use a regular browser with Tor (Tor the proxy not Tor Browser.)

To make a regular browser use Tor, you'll have install Tor and configure a browser to use it as a proxy.

## A Word of Warning

**Based on your question, I assume that anonymity isn't the reason you want to use Tor. You should be aware that in this setup does not provide any anonymity, even your real IP might me leaked. Regular browsers are simply not design to guard against this.**

## 1. Install Tor

**on Linux:** Just install tor via package manager. If you want a more up-to-date Tor version take a look at the [expert guides](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en).

**on Windows:** Duckduckgoing for it indicate that you need the [expert bundle](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en).

**on Mac:** The [wiki](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-osx.html.en) appears to have some instructions.

## 2. Configure Firefox

Open the preferences then go to Advanced → Network → Settings and change your proxy settings like this:

[image]

Should also work with other browsers, you just need to find the proxy settings.